# How to Change Export Label in MUI Datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Here's what current MUI Datagrid Export Label look likes.

[image]

I want to be able to change the label **Download as CSV** to something like **Export to CSV** etc

I've searched the Docs and issues on the github repo, i was unable to find how to progmatically change that label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/v6.0.1/packages/grid/x-data-grid/src/components/toolbar/GridToolbarExport.tsx#L32) there is not really a prop to change the text value.

I did however find a way to change it using `localeText`

```js
<DataGrid
  localeText={{
    toolbarExportCSV: "Export to CSV",
  }}
  ...
  slots={{
    toolbar: CustomToolbar,
  }}
/>
```

All other options can be found [here on github](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/blob/HEAD/packages/grid/x-data-grid/src/constants/localeTextConstants.ts)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, ```localeText={{ toolbarExportCSV: "Export to CSV" }}``` does the trick